# AIX syslog does not start after changing default port for remotely sending logs

Tags: logging, aix

On an AIX 7.2 machine I need to send the syslogs on a different machine and as instructed I have added my log server ip address in the /etc/syslog.conf file like this:

```
kern.debug;mail.debug;daemon.debug;syslog.debug;uucp.debug;local0.debug @11.11.11.11
```

Now I need to configure this to use a different port rather than the default 514/udp one to 601/tcp so I went and changed this line in the /etc/services file:

```
syslog                  514/udp         #
```

to

```
syslog                  601/tcp         #
```

Did a `refresh -s inetd; stopsrc -s syslogd; sleep 2; startsrc -s syslogd` even if I'm pretty sure that only `refresh -s syslog` should suffice and observed by issuing a `lssrc -s syslogd` that syslogd service is inactive.

Now I cannot debug this as I don't have any logs being generated anymore and my errpt doesn't show me anything either.

If I switch back to the 514/udp port the syslogd service will start up correctly.

Also tried to add the port number after in the /etc/syslog.conf file like this:

```
kern.debug;mail.debug;daemon.debug;syslog.debug;uucp.debug;local0.debug @11.11.11.11:601
```

but even if the syslogd is running, I don't see any change in logs being transmitted to the log server.

I do see 2 syslog-conn service being listed in the /etc/services file that point to the same 601 like this:

```
syslog                  514/udp         #
syslog-conn      601/tcp                # Reliable Syslog Service
syslog-conn      601/udp                # Reliable Syslog Service
```

but couldn't find anything related to this syslog-conn in IBM's documentation.

The output of `netstat -an | grep 514` is `udp        0      0  *.514                  *.*`

I can manualy connect usign telnet to 11.11.11.11 using port 601 from my machine.

So why I still cannot start the service using port 601 for syslog and finally,  what should I do in order to receive logs to the AIX server.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, AIX's syslog just don't know how to work in TCP. That's why it refuses to launch.
The old `syslogd` from Linux don't implement TCP logging too (see "Remote Logging" section on [this manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/8/syslogd))

To get your logging stack working with TCP, you'll probably have to use a more modern implementation like `syslog-ng`

Comment: Well, switching a service from udp to tcp is a _massive_ change in terms of how the receiver needs to work, and is not insignificant on the sender either. Changing a config file won't magically produce the necessary code.